# Python Schrödinger's Int/None

Tags: python, django, int, nonetype

This is a very strange issue.

I have some django admin code that takes a duration in seconds, rounds it up to the next minute, and multiplies it by 10. (The reason why is irrelevant here).

The code below gives me the following error:

unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

```
def charge(self, obj):
    return int((obj.duration + 59) / 60) * 10
```

If I test for None-ness, and then do the calculation, the code works:

```
def charge(self, obj):
    dur = obj.duration
    if dur is None:
        return dur
    else:
        return int((dur + 59) / 60) * 10
```

The result of obj.duration is the same in both cases.

What is going on here?

UPDATE -- Problem Understood: Although I 'solved' the issue with the if ... else ... lines, the real issue was that I didn't understand what was happening with obj. Here is the relevant page in the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: Maybe it is `None` in one case and not in another? And why is it a problem if you already solved it yourself?

Comment: The issue is in the code that generates `obj.duration`, it sometimes is `None`.

Comment: Obviously `obj.duration` might be `None`, we can't tell why if you won't share what you are passing as `obj`.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the code works"_? Do you mean that there is no exception, or do you mean that the calculation actually works? In your second code block, if `obj.duration` is `None` (and, assuming the same inputs, we know that it _is_ `None` from the earlier traceback) the calculation is avoided, and `charge()` returns `None`. Does that constitute "working"?

Comment: Btw you can probably reduce the conditional statements of None-checking function with a one-liner (ternary operator): `return dur if dur is None else int((dur + 59) / 60) * 10`

Comment: Probably your `obj` is 'lazy' object and it gets evaluated in boolean context, this leads to the behavior you described. In your code add `print(type(obj))`, `print(type(obj.duration))` just after the `def` and after `else` and please show the output.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys

Idos: obj is identical in both cases, which is why this puzzles me. It's a problem because obj.duration is non-None until it hits the calculation.

I want to know why so that I can avoid this issue in the future.

Eddo thanks for the simplification, much appreciated

Nikita I'll do that and add the output to the original question

Comment: Nikita: turns out the obj is a lazy object. Thanks for solving this puzzle.